# jQuery Change line-height in CSS depending on number of characters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have a Twitter widget on my site that displays our company's most recent tweet. If the tweet is over a certain length however, it does not fit in the container on the site and gets cut off. I would like to programmatically change the line-height css of the element depending on the number of characters in the tweet.

The CSS that defines this part of the element is shown here:

```
ul.tweet_list li{overflow-y: hidden;overflow-x: hidden;padding: 0.5em !important;height: 55px;line-height:55px;vertical-align: middle}
```

and on the page, the element is generated by only this code:

```
<div class="tweeter_widget"></div>
```

I need to detect if the tweet is over 'X' number of characters, and if so, change the line-height from 55px, to 24px. I'm not trying to vertically center text, but rather..

Example: http://justpaste.it/twitter-widget
If the text is too long, it cuts off around where you see the "white container" above it end. I want to change the line-height of this "bar" of text so that it will wrap to the next line AND stay in my "red" container.

In theory, this would be done with PHP, but I'm aware that I'll probably need to use jQuery.

EDIT: Here is the JS that produces the tweet:

```
/* Twitter initiates. Enter your username here. */
jQuery(function($){
      $(".tweeter_widget").tweet({
        join_text: "auto",
        username: "username",
        avatar_size: null,
        count: 1,
        auto_join_text_default: "",
        auto_join_text_ed: "",
        auto_join_text_ing: "",
        auto_join_text_reply: "",
        auto_join_text_url: "",
        loading_text: "loading tweets..."
      });
    });
```

Comment: Is the *actual problem* you're trying to solve "how to vertically center text"?

Comment: I updated the question... check the link for a screenshot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robasta/uKc66/2/)

```
var cnt =  $(".tweeter_widget").text().length;
if (cnt > 10) {
    $(".tweeter_widget").css("line-height", "5px"); 
}
```

ie:if more than ten characters in the div containing the Tweet, change the line-height.

Comment: Ok this works, but for some reason it throws it completely off the page. Like, it doesn't move it the correct amount of space or something. Where should I place this code?

Comment: Actually, the text doesn't display for some reason at all with this code..?

Comment: you can change the 5px to just 25px (5px is too small)

Comment: If the line-height property already exists, do I need to clear it before I update it with this code? I'm not sure why it's not displaying, but I'm thinking it's because this CSS property is being applied twice?

Comment: One more thing: The tweet is being displayed inside `ul.tweet_list li`, so how can I change the line height of this element if I CANNOT apply a class or id to this `li` element? For example, instead of changing the line-height in your code of `.tweeter_widget` I need to change the line height of `ul.tweet_list li`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8828/discussion-between-robert-dondo-and-adamdehaven)

Comment: Even setting the variable `var cnt =  $("#tweetDiv").text().length;` causes the text to not show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

Edited code to include in tweet DIV setter, though there's probably some work still do be done:

```
/* Twitter initiates. Enter your username here. */
jQuery(function($){
      $(".tweeter_widget").tweet({
        join_text: "auto",
        username: "username",
        avatar_size: null,
        count: 1,
        auto_join_text_default: "",
        auto_join_text_ed: "",
        auto_join_text_ing: "",
        auto_join_text_reply: "",
        auto_join_text_url: "",
        loading_text: "loading tweets..."
      });
      if ($(".tweeter_widget").html().length > X)
      {
         $(".tweeter_widget").css('line-height', '24px');
      }
});
```

Chances are since this updates dynamically, you'll want to delay this with some sort of callback. If I understand the tweet API correctly, you could use the filter parameter to do this:

```
/* Twitter initiates. Enter your username here. */
jQuery(function($){
      $(".tweeter_widget").tweet({
        join_text: "auto",
        username: "username",
        avatar_size: null,
        count: 1,
        auto_join_text_default: "",
        auto_join_text_ed: "",
        auto_join_text_ing: "",
        auto_join_text_reply: "",
        auto_join_text_url: "",
        loading_text: "loading tweets...",
        filter: function(t) { 
                   if (t.tweet_raw_text.length > X)
                   {
                      $(".tweeter_widget").css('lineheight', '24px');
                   }
                   return t;
                }

      });
});
```

I have not tested this code, of course.

Comment: I'm kind of new to JS... where would I place this? and what do I need to do so that it runs onLoad?

Comment: I edited the code at top to show the JS that produces the tweet. Could I put any code in there?

Comment: Yea, I think you could put it right before the last line; I'll edit my reply to show.