# How to increase the row height in HTML and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

can you please tell me how to increase the height of row (which is div ).I am appending data in a div .But I need to increase the height of div .Mean height Example :50 px .It mean after 50px new line will start ?

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/rgeHe/3/

```
   setInterval(function () {
$('#realTimeContents').append("Hiiiii. is div")


    }, 1000);
```

Comment: you can use line-height:50px for the same.

Comment: ok checking..in my fiddle

Comment: Not working please check my fiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Change line-height in CSS depending on number of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684835/jquery-change-line-height-in-css-depending-on-number-of-characters)

Comment: I agree for `line-height` property, if you want to set space between lines of text.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/rgeHe/3/

Comment: @GaneshPandhere not working your fiddle

Comment: What exactly is your question!? If you do not set an explicit height, the element's height automatically depends on its content!

Answer (score 0):

height for any object can be set on JQuery with `.height(20)` or as `.css("height","20")`

For an inline-block element (div is a block element) you might need to use `line-height` instead.

---

Note, If you are adding content & you want the height to increase, then you should be setting

```
height:auto
```

which is the default for div.

---

For you current problem, you rather need to be fixing a width, for the content to grow.

To take it the next line append a `<br/>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="realTimeContents"  style="width:100%;height:auto "> 
</div>  

 setInterval(function () {
$('#realTimeContents').append("<div height = '50' background = 'yellow'>Hiiiii. is div</div><br/>")


    }, 1000);
```